# Testing a local variable with JUnit and Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am writing a test case using `JUnit` and I am also using `Mockito` API wherever possible. `Collection<AppConfigTO> filteredCollection = CollectionUtils.select(configs, beanPredicate);` is the code where I am stuck on testing. I cannot mock `CollectionUtils` because I don't get `select()` while stubbing. If I don't use `Mockito` then how should I change the value of `filteredCollection` based on my need. I want it's size `>0` so that I can cover the second if statement in my `Cobertura` report.

Method under test:

```
public List<AppConfigTO> getAppConfig( String configCode ) {
    List<AppConfigTO> list = null;

    List<AppConfigTO> configs = getAppConfig();

    if( configs != null ) {
        EqualPredicate nameEqlPredicate = new EqualPredicate( configCode );
        BeanPredicate beanPredicate = new BeanPredicate("configCode", nameEqlPredicate);
        Collection<AppConfigTO> filteredCollection = CollectionUtils.select(configs, beanPredicate);

        if( filteredCollection != null && filteredCollection.size()>0 ) {
            list = new ArrayList<AppConfigTO>();
            for( AppConfigTO to : filteredCollection ) {
                list.add( to );
            }
        }
    }else{
        list = appConfigDao.getAppConfig(configCode);
    }

    return list;
}
```

JUnit test case:

```
@Test
   public void testGetAppConfig() throws Exception {
    AppConfigManager appManager = new AppConfigManager();
    cacheProvider = new TestAppConfigManager();

    IAppConfigManager configManager = Mockito.mock(IAppConfigManager.class);
    IAppConfigDao configDao = Mockito.mock(IAppConfigDao.class);

    List<AppConfigTO> list = new ArrayList<>();

    Mockito.when(configManager.getAppConfig()).thenReturn(list);
    Mockito.when(configDao.getAppConfig()).thenReturn(list);

    appManager.setAppConfigDao(configDao);
    list = appManager.getAppConfig(CONFIG_CODE);

    assertNull(list);
    assertNotNull(appManager.getAppConfigDao());
    assertSame("04852",this.CONFIG_CODE);
    assertNotNull(configManager.getAppConfig());

    // No ConfigManager
    appManager = new AppConfigManager();
    cacheProvider = new TestAppConfigManager();

    configManager = Mockito.mock(IAppConfigManager.class);
    configDao = Mockito.mock(IAppConfigDao.class);

    list = new ArrayList<>();

    Mockito.when(configManager.getAppConfig()).thenReturn(null);
    Mockito.when(configDao.getAppConfig()).thenReturn(null);

    appManager.setAppConfigDao(configDao);
    list = appManager.getAppConfig(CONFIG_CODE);    

    assertTrue(list.isEmpty());
    assertNotNull(appManager.getAppConfigDao());
    assertSame("04852",this.CONFIG_CODE);
    assertNull(configManager.getAppConfig());
}
```

Is there any way to do it so that I can proceed with testing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am also using Mockito API wherever possible.

Instead of using Mockito "wherever possible",
a better approach would be to use Mockito when *there's no better way*.

So you want to exercise the branch `filteredCollection.size()>0`. In the code I see that the content of this collection is determined by the `configCode` method parameter and the return value of `getAppConfig()`.
Use can easily control these. Use appropriate values for them to trigger the desired execution path.

Note that the test method `testGetAppConfig` is doing too many things.
A test case should test precisely one thing.
Split up this method to multiple independent test methods.

Btw, here's a better way to control the value returned by  `AppConfigManager.getAppConfig()`, without using mocks:

```
// fill this list appropriately
final List<AppConfigTO> dummyList = Arrays.asList(...);

AppConfigManager appManager = new AppConfigManager() {
    @Override
    public List<AppConfigTO> getAppConfig() {
        return dummyList;
    }
};
```

This technique is known as "extend and override".

Comment: You are right Janos and I think this is a cleaner way of dong it. I was even thinking to use PowerMockito but no more. Thank you.

Comment: Glad you like it, and that's really a good way of thinking, keep it up